# EFQ - sort by reference entity label

Tags: 8, entities

I'm trying to add an `sort` condition to an EFQ on an reference entity table, I think a code example explains this better.

```
$query = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->getQuery();
$ids = $query->condition('type', 'some_type')
  ->condition('some_more', 'conditions')
  ->sort('a_term_field', 'ASC')
  ->execute();
```

Now what happens is that the nodes will be sorted by the term id (since that is what is stored in the field table) but I would like to sort on the term label instead. Is something like that possible with EFQs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `->sort('a_term_field.entity.name', 'ASC')`, that should work.

Some limitations exists with multilingual fields, as it is not defined on which language it should be sorted.

Comment: Works like a charm, did I miss documentation for this feature or is it just a hidden gem?

Comment: You mean relationship support in general? (this works for conditions as well btw). I thought I've seen some documentation about this but all I cound find for now is the change record: https://www.drupal.org/node/1882418